# Delphi - Twebbrowser and Screenshot function. Bug?

Tags: delphi, screenshot, twebbrowser

When I try to take a screenshot (of a foreground window) after navigating on a Twebbrowser, function screenshot() tries to capture but creates a screenshot.bmp of 0kb.

This only reproduces when I Webbrowser1.Navigate(url) first.
If I don't navigate it takes a screenshot of any window normally.

(If i dont hide Form2 i can take a screenshot of the form after navigating on twebbrowser, but that's not what i intended with Screenshot() )

PS: I edited windows reg entry keys to use IE11;

Here's the code :

```
procedure ScreenShot();

const
  FullWindow = false;
var
  Win: HWND;
  DC: HDC;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  FileName: string;
  WinRect: TRect;
  Width: Integer;
  Height: Integer;

begin
  Form2.Hide;
  try
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    Win := GetForegroundWindow;

    if FullWindow then
    begin
      GetWindowRect(Win, WinRect);
      DC := GetWindowDC(Win);
    end 
    else
    begin
      Windows.GetClientRect(Win, WinRect);
      DC := GetDC(Win);
    end;
    try
      Width := WinRect.Right - WinRect.Left;
      Height := WinRect.Bottom - WinRect.Top;

      Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        Bmp.Height := Height;
        Bmp.Width := Width;
        BitBlt(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, DC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        FileName := 'Screenshot_' +
                    FormatDateTime('mm-dd-yyyy-hhnnss', Now());
        Bmp.SaveToFile(Format('./screenshot.bmp', [FileName]));
      finally
        Bmp.Free;
      end;
    finally
      ReleaseDC(Win, DC);
    end;
  finally
    Form2.Show;
    sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screenshot();
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Webbrowser1.Navigate('http://www.google.pt/');
end;
```

Comment: First off, get rid of that `Application.ProcessMessages` and try again.

Comment: Have you tried to see the result of BitBlt and the error code after running it? If your output is 0k BitBlt failed and it should be quite specific why

Comment: Commented Application.ProcessMessages, same.
Dont really know how to check BitBlt result (saw function on another post, lazy me :P)

I've tried to create Twebbrowser in runtime, navigate, destroy it and tri to screenshot. same happens. after navigate, can't use screenshot() properly.

(resetting application after Navigate it's not an option)

Comment: Read the documentation for the `BitBlt` API function. Stack Overflow frowns upon "lazy" people.

Comment: It must have something to do with your registry hack.. it seems to work fine without it..

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try with standard IE, i needed to set registry to use IE11 , because .js were not executing in standard IE.

and let's take a look at BitBlt then :)

Comment: Run again w/ standard IE and after using navigate BitBlt returns 0kb ...

Comment: What does the `BitBlt` *function* return? Does it return True or False?

Comment: If it's what's visible in TWebBrowser you want in the bitmap, have a look at [OleDraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692711.aspx)

Comment: I've read msdn documentation and still can't get BitBlt value, i know it has to be nonzero to succeed thoug... lol

eitherway, i think im gonna use this script
https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/screenCapture.bat

through a shellexecute() . 

It must work, problem is, the script captures window title and i'll have to change all my var's coordinates.

Comment: This can't be possible....

    using the script above to take screenshots trhough a shellexecute(), reproduces the exact same problem... If i navigate on a twebbrowser.. i can no longer take screenshots ....

Comment: I'm not understanding how your file assignment works.. shouldn't it be Bmp.SaveToFileFormat(%s, Filename) ?

Comment: Indeed, the way you're choosing the filename makes no sense. Are you sure you're looking at the correct file? Your code seems to assume it will be one filename, but actually saves it as an entirely different filename.

Comment: it saves it as screenshot.bmp. i check every time.
i can take infinite screenshots and overwrite.
as long as i press to tweb.navigate. i can't take any more screenshots. it gives me a 0kb output screenshot.bmp

even if i do anything else with the Twebbrowser, for ex: tBwebrowser.Stop.. i dont even enter a page and it messes with Screenshot() output.

i dont know... 

how is Twebbrowser rendered on Delphi? unique explanation is tha it is rendered with BitBlt aswell, and by rendering the Twebbrowser, i can't use same render on Screenshot() .

just a newbie 50cent :/